# Using a Proc and nil?, i need to check if an array has a nil element or not in ruby

Tags: ruby

```
    def check_nill(array1)
      p = Proc.new {array1.any? { |x| x.nil? }}
      if p == true
        puts "true"  
      else  
        puts "false"  
      end 
     end
```

it always give me false and i dont know why

Comment: Why do you need a Proc there?

Comment: its a hacker rank exercise, it ask me for a proc.

Comment: You are defining the proc each time the method is called. The variable `p` holds the proc, not the result of evaluating it. `p` holds the proc object, so `p == true #=> false`. Move the definition outside the method and evaluate it inside the method.

Comment: `array1.any?(&:nil?)` would technically use a proc and `nil?`.

Comment: Off-topic, but I'd strongly advise against using `p` as a variable name, since it's the name of a method used for printing with inspection.

Answer (score 2):

`Proc.new` does not actually run the code. You have to pass it over, or call it using [`Proc#call`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Proc.html#method-i-call).

```
is_nil = Proc.new {|item| item.nil?}
["a", "b", nil].any?(is_nil)
# => true
```

Your code always return `false` because `p` was an instance of `Proc`, and not the result of the block.

```
p = Proc.new {array1.any? { |x| x.nil? }} # <Proc:0x0000000>

if p == true # <Proc:0x0000000> == true? no
  puts "true"  
else
  puts "false" # prints false
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overdoing it, creating a proc inside a method and then not calling it.

```
  check_nil = proc {|ar| ar.any?{|x| x.nil?} # or just proc {|ar| ar.any?(nil)}

  puts check_nil.call([1,2,nil,3]) # => true
```